# React Native swiper not working in StackNavigator for IOS

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation, stack-navigator, react-native-swiper

In my app, I have *Login Screen*, *ForgotPassword Screen* and *SignUp Screen*. In **SignUp Screen** I have used [react-native-swiper](https://github.com/leecade/react-native-swiper) to displays three step's slides of signup process. And I have wrap-up these screens in **StackNavigator** and render this **StackNavigator** as a root component in my **App.js**.

Here is my **StackNavigator** :

**Router.js**

```js
import { createDrawerNavigator, createAppContainer, createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import Login from './src/containers/Login';
import SignUp from './src/containers/SignUp';
import ForgotPassword from './src/containers/ForgotPassword';

const AuthStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    Login: {
        screen: Login
    },
    ForgotPassword: {
        screen: ForgotPassword
    },
    SignUp: {
        screen: SignUp
    },
});

const Router = createAppContainer(AuthStackNavigator)

export default Router
```

**App.js**

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import configureStore from './src/store/configureStore';
import Router from './Router';

const store = configureStore()

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <Router />
            </Provider>            
        );
    }
}

export default App
```

**SignUp.js**

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, KeyboardAvoidingView, Platform, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import Swiper from 'react-native-swiper';
import Colors from '../../config/Colors';
import Logo from '../components/Logo';
import MText from '../components/MText';
import StepButton from '../components/StepButton';
import SignUpStepOne from './SignUpStepOne';
import SignUpStepTwo from './SignUpStepTwo';
import SignUpStepThree from './SignUpStepThree';

class SignUp extends Component {

  static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => ({
    header: null
  });

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      activeStep: 0
    };
  }

  slideToNext = () => {
    this.swiper.scrollBy(1, true);
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      activeStep: prevState.activeStep + 1
    }))
  }

  slideToPrev = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      activeStep: prevState.activeStep - 1
    }), () => {
      this.swiper.scrollBy(-1, true);
    })
  }

  render() {
      <KeyboardAvoidingView style={styles.container} behavior="padding">
        <View style={{ flex: 1, paddingHorizontal: 10 }}>

          <Logo />

          <Swiper
            style={{
              
            }}
            ref={(swiper) => { this.swiper = swiper; }} 
            containerStyle={{ flex: 1 }}
            showsButtons={false}
            showsPagination={false}
            loop={false}
            scrollEnabled={false}
            onIndexChanged={(activeStep) => {
              this.setState({
                activeStep
              })
            }}
          >
            <SignUpStepOne onNext={this.slideToNext} />
            <SignUpStepTwo onNext={this.slideToNext} onPrev={this.slideToPrev} />
            <SignUpStepThree onNext={this.slideToNext} onPrev={this.slideToPrev} />
          </Swiper>

        </View>
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
  }
}
```

But, the problem is that when I navigate from **Login screen** to **SignUp screen** using `this.props.navigation.navigate('SignUp')`, **Swiper** componen not displaying anything in SignUp screen. It just blank. For android it working properly, For IOS it is not working.

And another thing to note is that If I just render SignUp screen as a root in **App.js** then it is working properly.

And also If I set **SignUp** screen as a initial screen in my StackNavigator then also it's working.

Please anyone help me what's going wrong here ?

Comment: Could you try Change `this.props.navigation.navigate('SignUp')` => `this.props.navigation.push('SignUp')`

Comment: Thank for comment @hongdevelop, But it's not worked.

Comment: Can I see your signupstep page?

Comment: I don't know much about Redux, but I think it's Redux who's making problems.

Comment: It just form with `TextInput` and next, previous button.

Comment: I mean I want to look at this SignUpStepOne, SignUpStepTwo.

Comment: @hongdevelop SignUpStepOne, SignUpStepTwo and SignUpStepThree is my custom component in which I have created long forms. So I am not able to saw you. However If I just set `<View><Text>Step 1</Text></View>` and so on for three steps in swiper still simple text is also not displaying.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I Have found the solution.

Add `removeClippedSubviews={false}` props to swiper. Then It will work.

Answer (score 1):

If Swiper isn't working use these props

```
removeClippedSubviews={false}
scrollEnabled={true}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).